# Cross compiling gRPC using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, grpc

I'm trying to cross-compile a gRPC using cmake.

I actually managed to do it. Unfortunately my method involves tinkering inside CMakeLists.txt.

Problem was that, when I was trying to compile gRPC it was using protobuffer he just compiled. It cannot run ARM compiled executables on x86 machine.

I managed to compile it by specifying path to protoc and grpc_cpp_plugin manually in gRPCs main CMakeLists.txt. It is dirty and since I would like to include gRPC as submodule I need clean way to do it.

Has anyone managed to cross-compile gRPC using cmake?

Comment: According to gRPC's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L65), it accepts `gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER` parameter. By setting this parameter to "package" (either in CMake GUI or as `-D` option to `cmake`) you will force the build process to use already installed Protobuf. Next step will be to make `find_package(Protobuf)` to find your installed version.

Comment: I did try it. Unfortunately it also uses libs. And libs are compiled to x86. I don't know how to tell gRPC to use plugins from my machine and libs it just compiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This way should work:

1. Cross-compile Protobuf for target(ARM) and install it.

   Make sure that cross-compiled Protobuf can be searched in the toolchain(ARM) you have. 
   E.g. it is installed into system-default prefix under sysroot.
2. On host, install Protobuf **of the same version**. It needn't to be searchable (that is, user-local installation is sufficient).
3. Cross-compile gRPC with following parameters (set in CMake GUI or as `-D` option for `cmake` executable):

   - gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER: package
   - gRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE: MODULE
   - Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE: <path to your host `protoc` executable>

#### Explanations

Setting parameter `gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROVIDER` to "package" tells gRPC to not build its own Protobuf, but use already installed variant. This variant is searched by `find_package(Protobuf)`.

Setting parameter `gRPC_PROTOBUF_PACKAGE_TYPE` to "MODULE" tells gRPC to not use "Config" file, provided by Protobuf installation, for detect Protobuf things (libraries and executable). Config file contains hardcoded paths which cannot be adjusted outside. Instead, [FindProtobuf.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/module/FindProtobuf.html) script is used for find Protobuf.

Setting parameter `Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE` tells `FindProtobuf.cmake` script to not search Protobuf executable, but takes it from the parameter.

Comment: You my man are THE BEST! I've managed to build standalone gRPC instance on clean repository. I only need to add it to my project. Now tell me, how can i provide you with a beer you earned?

Comment: I've been happy to early... there is still an issue with grpc_cpp_plugin. I've got it installed on my machine but build uses projects version. In line 182 of CMakeLists.txt there is: `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$<TARGET_FILE:grpc_cpp_plugin>`. There is no variable that I could tinker with... Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you need those plugins? If not, then you can disable them by setting `gRPC_BUILD_CODEGEN` parameter to off. But if you need those plugins, then I bet that cross-compiling of gRPC without modifying its CMakeLists.txt is impossible...

Comment: Regarding "Make sure that cross-compiled Protobuf can be searched in the toolchain(ARM) you have. E.g. it is installed into system-default prefix under sysroot."


I've built protobuf with NDK.
How can I tell CMake to use the protobuf (build) path when building gRPC? Or how can I setup this sysroot?

Thank you.

Comment: @Horst: If you have a sysroot, then tell CMake about it by using `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable. That way your installations under sysroot will be checked by CMake when search things (packages, libraries, executables). You may also tell CMake to not search these things on the host, by setting variables like [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_*](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM.html).

Comment: In gRPC v1.55.1, you should use -D_gRPC_PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE and -D_gRPC_CPP_PLUGIN