# How to integrate protobuf with cmake?

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I need to integrate protobuf 3 into my app. Since it's multiplatform and multiarchitecture, I cannot simply install protobuf into my system and use the cmake  include function like this:

```
INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
```

because it'll only work for x86_64 (the architecture into which I'm installing it)

My idea was to call the protobuf's Makefile through my CMakeLists.txt but it's not that simple, because the project has a configure.

I tried to find protobuf cmake integrations on github but they're all for protobuf2.

What can I do in this situation?

**UPDATE:**

I added, in my project,

```
add_subdirectory(${DEPENDENCIES}/protobuf/cmake _protobuf)
```

Because I found CMakeLists.txt in `protobuf/cmake`: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/master/cmake

However I stil cannot call

```
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRC PROTO_HEADER message.proto)
```

because that's defined in https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/d9ccd0c0e6bbda9bf4476088eeb46b02d7dcd327/cmake/protobuf-module.cmake.in

I tried then generating and including it:

```
configure_file(${DEPENDENCIES}/protobuf/cmake/protobuf-module.cmake.in
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/protobuf-module.cmake @ONLY)
include(protobuf-module.cmake)
```

but then I get errors in `protobuf-module.cmake` like

```
-- Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE Protobuf_LIBRARIES) (found version "")

  Unknown CMake command "protobuf_generate".
```

Comment: If you want to *cross-compile* project which uses protobuf and `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` function, then you need to have **two variants** of Protobuf on the build machine: the one built for the **host** and one built for the **target**. Add `find_package(Protobuf MODULE)` to your `CMakeLists.txt` and make sure it finds **target** variant of Protobuf. But set variable `Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE` pointed to the **host** executable. See that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202453/cross-compiling-grpc-using-cmake/52204064#52204064) for more details.